# Distinct roots and multiplicity of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I encountered these two doubts while solving a polynomial problem.

1. A real polynomial of degree $2n$ that's non negative for all real $x$ has $2$ distinct real roots. If one of the roots have multiplicity of $k$, then can we say the other root has a multiplicity of $2n-k$?
2. Can we say the same if those $2$ distinct roots are complex and not necessarily real?

Comment: How can it be "positive for all real $x$"  and have real roots?  Did you possibly mean "non-negative" instead of "positive"?

Comment: @lulu oh yes you're right. I meant non negative. Let me edit the post. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: But, in that case, consider something like $(x^2-1)^2(x^2+1)$.

Comment: @lulu that has 2 real roots with multiplicity of 2 for each one right?

Comment: Exactly.  $\quad$

Comment: @lulu oh I get it. So 1 is incorrect, is 2 similarly incorrect too?

Comment: For complex roots, the claim is obviously true.  The sum of the multiplicities of the roots must always be the degree of the polynomial.  In order for a polynomial to have exactly two complex roots it must be of the form $c(x-r_1)^{d_1}(x-r_2)^{d_2}$

Comment: @lulu oh. I'm a bit confused, if the sum of multiplicities of all the roots is indeed the degree of the polynomial, then why didn't it work for  $(x^2-1)^2(x^2+1)$? Is it because it has a pair of complex roots which each has a multiplicity of 1? Is this correct?

Comment: The real numbers are different than the complex numbers.  For a polynomial with real or complex coefficients, we know it must factor completely over the complex numbers.  This is false over the real numbers.  $x^2+1$ has no real roots but it equals $(x-i)(x+i)$ over the complex numbers.